# GTK character count vs byte index

Tags: c, string, encoding, gtk, cyrillic

In a GtkTextBuffer,

I can see that GTK+ stores cyrillic characters in two bytes (which confuses me a little, I thought it stores them UTF-8 encoded, hence every character has to be within a single byte?)

This leads to a problem - I am scanning the text as a string in a loop and I need to refer to the appropriate character location based on the index in the loop, however they don't have corresponding indices anymore, because the text contains cyrillic. The character count is 8310 and the size of the string is around 11300.

If I use `g_str_to_ascii()` on the string I am scanning, later on, when I display some of the content of the string on a tree view widget it displays cyrillic characters as `?`s.

How do I get around this problem?

---

```
G_MODULE_EXPORT void on_textbuffer_changed (GtkTextBuffer* textbuffer, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkTextIter start   = {0};
    GtkTextIter end     = {0};
    gchar*      text    = NULL;

    gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds(textbuffer, &start, &end);

    text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text(textbuffer, &start, &end, FALSE);

    printf("[%i][%i]\n", gtk_text_buffer_get_char_count(textbuffer), strlen(text));

    g_free(text);
}
```

This will print out `[1][2]` if I place cyrillic character and `[2][4]` if I place two cyrillic characters respectively.

Those are the bytes of the cyrillic "а" (char/dec):

[image]

Comment: There's a misconception about UTF-8 here: it's a variable length encoding (1-4 bytes per character) and this is the reason for what you are seeing.

Comment: @jku I see. My area of expertise is not encoding and I am indeed very confused. I thought as it is UTF-8 it is a byte-length encoding :) However if I don't solve this at the end I will have to create a cyrillic-to-latin character transliterator and replace cyrillic characters with their latin counterpart.

Comment: UTF-8 can use 1 to 4 bytes to encode a char. One option: you could convert the UTF-8 buffer to UTF-16 and use the indexes of the latter.

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear what you want to do but if you just need to process the whole UTF-8 string one Unicode character at a time, the [GLib Unicode manipulation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html) functions might help, see e.g. g_utf_next_char() and g_utf_get_char().

This doesn't change the fact that the characters are Unicode so may be multi-byte characters.

If your goal is to be able to modify the buffer based on e.g. matching words, you should look at the GtkTextIter API: As an example you can use [gtk_text_iter_forward_search ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextIter.html#gtk-text-iter-forward-search) to get start and end iters that you can use directly in the GtkTextBuffer API. This way you'll never need to deal with the actual character or byte indexes.

Comment: In another words Imagine the string "Hello World" and it is set on the gtk text buffer. I want to get the character position of "W" in the text buffer out of the index 6. It is encoding problem.

Comment: Directly accessing character at index 6 is just not possible (except with code that goes through all the characters and stops at index 6).... but I think there may be other solutions if you explain what you really want to achieve: Why are you doing this? Where does the index 6 come from?

Comment: I already explained I am scanning the contents of the text buffer as a string. Say I want to match some word and select it in the text buffer.

Comment: I don't think you explained that you actually want to match a word and select it in the buffer :)

Comment: I've added a note about GtkTextIter API that is probably what you want in this case.

Comment: So as I am scanning the UTF-8 string in a per-byte manner I need to keep track at which character offset (rather than byte index) I am at in the text buffer. Yes I did not initially mention exactly what I want to do. Just the problem. I know that API I will see if I can do it.

Comment: It is actually a parser that extracts specific numbers onto a tree view and I want to keep their position and select their source location in the GtkTextView (when the tree view cursor changes) for which `gtk_text_iter_forward_search()` will not be very useful and also very performance-needy. I was thinking to scan it using `gtk_text_iter_forward_char()` though. In fact I tried, but since I don't know how to deal with gunichar, the result was messy.

Comment: Ok, with proper handling and the use of the `GtkTextIter` API, I did it. I hope it is not much slower.